# HTML hyperlink text problems

Tags: html, hyperlink

I know this is going to sound stupid but I'm just getting started in HTML and have a question. I'm trying to create a hyperlink that states "Visit the Marion Technical College Web site to learn more about interactive media." The part that is supposed to be the hyperlink is "Marion Technical College." Everything works, but the problem is that my hyperlink starts at "Visit" and runs to the end of "College." I need it to just be Marion Technical College. Here is the line I put in:

```
<h6>Visit the <a href="http://www.mtc.edu"> Marion Technical College</a> Web site to learn more about interactive media.</h6>
```

It works on here, but does not show like that when I open the file in Edge or Chrome. No browser shows the hyperlink correctly, but this site does.

Comment: I just fixed your question to show the actual HTML source. Looks perfect to me for what you need.

Comment: Put what you want the link to say after .ecu:>

Comment: Thanks Evert! Thanks mlegg, I have the text there it's just not showing right when I open the file.

Comment: Might be an CSS issue? Can you post a link to a working example?

Comment: The problem is most likely due to (a) the surrounding content (you should provide a complete [mcve]) and (b) an error that could be detected if you used http://validator.w3.org/nu/

Comment: I don't really have a working example because the code works, it just doesn't display correctly. Here is a link to my entire file on pastebin https://pastebin.com/58xvrxYj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot the closing `>` bracket on the image that's before that line. If you insert it, it's displayed correctly:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/XHTML1-TRANSITIONAL.DTD">
<HTML xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<html>
  <body>
    <h1><center>Gary Hicks</center></h1>
    <hr size=2 color="red" width="50%">
    <pre><center>This website contains examples of assignments
completed in the Fall of 2017 for OIS1520A</center>
    <ul>
    <li><b><i>Week 1</i></b></li>
    <ol><a href="http://www.mtc.edu"> In-Class Page</a></ol>
    <ol><a href="http://www.mtc.edu"> Link to Word Document</a></ol>
    <li>Week 2</li>
    <li>Week 3</li>
    <li>Week 4</li>
    <li>Week 5</li>
    <li>Week 6</li>
    <li>Week 7</li>
    <li>Week 8</li>
    <li>Week 9</li>
    <li>Week 10</li>
    <li>Week 11</li>
    <li>Week 12</li>
    <li>Week 13</li>
    <li>Week 14</li>
    <li>Week 15</li>
    <li>Week 16</li>
    </ol>
    <center><a href="http://www.mtc.edu" target="_new"><img src="logo.gif"></a></center>
<h6>Visit the <a href="http://www.mtc.edu">Marion Technical College</a> Web site to learn more about interactive media.</h6>
  </body>
</html>
```

P.S.: You also had one `<hr` too much in the `hr` tag further up. I also removed that in this snippet. Plus you don't seem to close the `<pre>` tag anywhere...

Comment: Wow, that was it. Added in the closing bracket and it displays perfectly in every browser now. Thank you! That has been driving me crazy for about 3 hours now.

Comment: I upvoted but I see no way to mark this as answered.